# Node.js Axios request

Tags: node.js, request, axios

How to pass this Python code to Node.js code?

```
rc = requests.get(url).json()
auth_url = rc['a']
pin_url = rc['b'] 
client_id = rc['c']
```

As I can pass this same code to Node.Js (ES6) I have tried to use the module of https://github.com/request/request and that of https://github.com/axios/axios but these work with promises and not I have been able to assign the value that the request returns since the execution ends before I get the promise (I am new to Node.JS)

I tried something like that

```
class urls {

    getRc (){
        return Axios.get(urlconfig)
    }

    async getAuthUrl(){
        this.getRc().then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
    }

}

module.exports = urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the system-sleep module - this will make it wait x seconds or whatever - note this module is a hack but its a quick win for you if you are just playing around.

This is happening because in Node.js you can't pause the main thread. However, if you were running a server or a React app or something, this wouldn't be an issue.